# Apache beam v2.50.0 NoClassDefFound - /MemoryMonitorOptions

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While updating the Apache Beam version from 2.46.0 to 2.50.0 for Java based Dataflow, the mvn package command runs successfully. However while executing the mvn compile:exec script - we are getting an error "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/options/MemoryMonitorOptions**"

No updates in pom file except for the update in Apache beam version -
[WARNING]
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9662373Z java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/options/MemoryMonitorOptions
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9665631Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9668538Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1022)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9670605Z     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:174)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9672586Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:555)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9674516Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:458)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9676939Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:452)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9678816Z     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9690248Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:451)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9692252Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:594)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9694175Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:527)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9696026Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9699991Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1022)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9704965Z     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:174)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9706908Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:555)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9708814Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:458)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9710696Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:452)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9712552Z     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9714469Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:451)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9716698Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:594)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9718622Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:527)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9720635Z     at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineRegistrar$Options.getPipelineOptions (DataflowPipelineRegistrar.java:40)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9722611Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.initializeRegistry (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:2090)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9724487Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache. (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:2083)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9726421Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache. (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:2047)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9728327Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.resetCache (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:581)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9730230Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory. (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:547)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9732113Z     at cio.mmt.PubSubTopicsToBigQuery.main (PubSubTopicsToBigQuery.java:55)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9734009Z     at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9743608Z     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9745720Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.sdk.options.MemoryMonitorOptions
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9748376Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:476)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9750298Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:594)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9752205Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:527)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9754041Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9756293Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1022)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9758225Z     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:174)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9760115Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:555)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9761982Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:458)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9763915Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:452)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9765721Z     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9767732Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:451)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9769643Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:594)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9771552Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:527)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9821607Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9824027Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1022)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9825945Z     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:174)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9827873Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:555)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9829648Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:458)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9831550Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:452)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9833326Z     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9835504Z     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:451)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9837376Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:594)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9839129Z     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:527)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9840848Z     at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineRegistrar$Options.getPipelineOptions (DataflowPipelineRegistrar.java:40)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9846061Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.initializeRegistry (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:2090)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9847894Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache. (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:2083)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9849601Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache. (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:2047)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9851239Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.resetCache (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:581)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9852896Z     at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory. (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:547)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9854577Z     at cio.mmt.PubSubTopicsToBigQuery.main (PubSubTopicsToBigQuery.java:55)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9856188Z     at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9857817Z     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9885576Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9885795Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9886047Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9886514Z [INFO] Total time:  8.555 s
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9886767Z [INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-12T10:39:17Z
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9887048Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-10-12T10:39:17.9934156Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) on project bigquery: An exception occured while executing the Java class. org/apache/beam/sdk/options/MemoryMonitorOptions: org.apache.beam.sdk.options.MemoryMonitorOptions -> [Help 1]

Updated the pom.xml file by removing - plugins.
Also update the Java class file to import only specific required class files.

mvn compile exec should have completed successfully and staging location/template location should have the new class files compiled and generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the class `MemoryMonitorOptions` has been [deprecated](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.50.0/index.html?deprecated-list.html) in version 2.50.0 hence the NoClassDefFound error. You will need to revisit your codes and update all lines referenced to the `MemoryMonitorOptions` class.

Adding this [SDK version support status](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status) document to keep you posted on other version deprecation schedules.

Comment: beamsdkio version was on old version and hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whats the version picked up on the dataflow console, seems like your pipeline is not importing the right Dataflow package or the Beam version. Also you can try using fat jar so that all required Classes of the concerned version is available.